# Need CSS formatting help for text drop down / up menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I got the the drop down menu to work using text instead of an image and I got the drop down menu to actually go up (added bottom: 100%; to nav li ul) but I still can't seem to get the CSS formatting right.

Below is a link to my test page as well as the style sheet...

1. Need help making my footer navigation be in one line instead of having the new drop down Services menu on it's own line.
2. Need to simply center the drop down / up sub menu items when you hover over the main Services link.

http://wsgdev.com/ceiltex/indextest.html

http://wsgdev.com/ceiltex/styles.css

Thanks so much in advance for any help!

Comment: remove the `width: 100%` and add `display: inline-block` to the nav element (style.css line 27)

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH THAT DID IT! I also figured out the alignment issue with the drop down / up menu.

Thanks again!!!

Comment: great... i created an answer just so the question can be "closed"

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `width: 100%` and add `display: inline-block` to the nav element (style.css line 27)

- read more about [inline and block elements](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/block_vs_inline_elements.htm)